# Number of edges in Graph where neighbors are 2-element subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with a common element

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

*Let $n\ge2$ be an integer. For the simple graph $G_n$, define the set of nodes as the set of subsets of size 2 from the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, where nodes are neighbors iff they have a common element. For example, for $n\ge3$, the nodes $\{1,2\}$ and $\{1,3\}$ are neighbors of $G_n$. Find the number of edges for $G_{100}$*

I figured to find the number of edges, I should just find the number of 2-element subsets that share a common element. I know the total number of subsets of size 2 should equal $n \choose 2$, but I'm stuck on how to find the number of these subsets that share a common element.

Should I try finding the number of subsets with no common elements and subtract that from $ n \choose 2$ or is there a more direct way? Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is the correct one.  For a given vertex (i.e. $2$-element subset) try to figure out how many are its neighbor.

This is the same for each vertex, so it's enough to do this for the node $\{1,2\}$.  You *could* do this directly, and just count the number that have a $1$ and the number that have a $2$: since it has to be a distinct subset (i.e. it can't have both a $1$ and a $2$), it must consist of:

- a one or two
- a number in $\{3,4,\ldots,n\}$.

We have two choices for picking the $1$ or $2$, and $n - 2$ choices for the others.  This means each node has degree $2\cdot (n-2)$.  To see how this relates to the number of edges, consider what happens when you add up all of the degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Each edge consists of three elements $\{i,j,k\}$, with exactly one of these three elements shared by the two nodes, yielding $$\binom{n}{3}3=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$$ edges in total.  For $n=100$, this is $485100$.